# Is it sensible to ask for the lemma of an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, lemmas

Is lemma defined for adverbs? For example, what is the lemma of *diagonally*? An even more difficult example would be "What is the lemma of *nationally*?" Is it *nationally*, *national* ,or *nation*? Or lemma is simply the word itself, for adverbs?

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)) it says that lemma is the canonical form chosen from a lexeme (a set of forms carrying the same meaning). Is it true if I say that since *diagonally* and *diagonal* doesn't carry the same meaning (even it changes word class), then the two of them is not part of the same lexeme, and hence one can't be the lemma of another?

If that's the case, then is there any example of an adverb that has a different lemma?

I've read this question: [What is the notion of lemma?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4073/what-is-the-notion-of-lemma) but it doesn't seem to answer my question directly (and there is no answer in that question either).

Comment: In a language where adverbs are not inflected, it seems that any adverb
is trivially its own lemma. So the question should possibly be: *are
there languages where adverbs can be inflected?*. If the answer is no,
it might be interesting to understand why.

Comment: Your comment is actually an answer to one of my question: "Is there any example of an adverb that has a different lemma?". Would you like to expand and put it as an answer?

Comment: @babou English is such a language.  For example, *better* and *best* are inflected forms of both the adjective *good* and the adverb *well*; *worse* and *worst* are inflected forms of both the adjective *bad* and the adverb *badly*.

Comment: @snailboat You are right. I was writing that in my answer while you wrote the comments. Unfortunately, English not being my mother togue led me to choose a bad example ... se correction forthcoming in answer.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this question is downvoted without explanation on this beta site.

Comment: As I always say. *a downvote shows that someone is foolish*, at least when not explained. Which leave much room for interpretation. But StackOverflow, where you have rep, has its own unexplained downvotes by people who believe an accepted answer is the ultimate truth ... even when it is wrong. - - - - Then you should avoid looking down on beta sites ...  they may have very good users.

Comment: @babou: I'm not sure I understand you clearly. My intention was not to undermine beta sites, but asking for comments as to find what I can improve from the question.

Comment: I support 100% people who ask explanation for downvotes, I actually suggested anonymous (or pseudonymous) comments for downvoters who do not want to be identified, and I have more to say on this issue.  But the fact that the site is beta was irrelevant, and mentioning it together with a criticism can be interpreted negatively.

Comment: Ah, I see. What I meant was, I actually expected the quality of beta sites to be better compared to larger sites, since most people in beta should be the ones more concerned with the well-being of the new site. And so a downvote without comment is against my expectation of a beta site. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If adverbs are an independent part of speech that cannot be inflected,
it follows from the definitions you give (which I also checked in
Wikipedia), that any adverb is trivially its own lemma.

That may be often the case in English (not my mother tongue, in case
it was not noticed). But not always: for example, some short adverbs
can be inflected for comparative and superlatives like adjectives are:
such as "fast", "faster", "fastest". In this case, all three adverbs
lemmatise to "fast".

*Correction:* "fast" may be seen as an adjective used adverbially, while
the corresponding French "vite" is an adverb, and does not inflect,
hence my possibly improper choice for an example. I was trying to get an
exemple different from "well - better - best" (given in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Uses))
though even well can be seen as an adjective as in "he is well". This seems less the
case for "badly - worse - worst".

It seems somewhat difficult to find a clear example since words formed and used as adverbs, such as "kindly" from "kind", can be inflected but are also used as adjectives.

No other example coming to my mind at this time, I am leaving it open for people who have a better knowledge of English.

Actually, there are [different kinds of adverbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Adverbs_as_a_.22catch_all.22_category), playing different
roles in sentences, and it seems that some such classes are not inflected at
all.

It may also vary with languages, though a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Adverbs_in_specific_languages) seems to suggest that adverbs almost never inflect (at least they never say they do).
The only exception seems to be [Austronesian languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_languages), the best example being a widely known word "wiki" which has "wikiwiki" as comparative.

Comment: I just realized two French adverbs a specific form for comparative,
*bien - mieux* and *mal - pire*, same as in English. Does it extend to other languages?

Comment: It's the norm in Standard Average European but not on its periphery.  My sense is that the agglutinative languages, being highly regular, do not have it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very sensible to me, as I, too, am trying to understand the relationship between lemmas and lexemes.

In addition to what others have said about comparatives and superlatives, I believe regional differences in spelling should be categorized under the same lemma: *colorfully* and *colourfully* share the lemma "colorfully" (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). And they also share a lexeme.

I will argue here that there are cases where two words form a lemma yet don't share a lexeme. In biology, a *chimeric* organism is a type of genetic hybrid; in art/culture, a *chimerical* idea is a type of mixed up thought. Since a biologist wouldn't speak of a *chimerical organism* and an artist wouldn't say a *chimeric idea* ([see Ngram Viewer chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chimeric%20gene%2C%20chimerical%20gene%2Cchimeric%20idea%2C%20chimerical%20idea&year_start=1988&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchimeric%20gene%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimerical%20idea%3B%2Cc0)), shouldn't these be classed as separate lexemes? Yet, grammatically, they are both adjectives with slightly different inflections (*Calvinist/Calvinistic* is another example), so shouldn't they share a lemma?

To finally get back to adverbs, then, what are we to do with *chimerically*? Both the biologist and the social scientist have to share this since there is no *chimericly* ([Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chimeric%2Cchimerical%2Cchimerically%2Cchimericly%2Cchimaeric%2Cchimaerical%2Cchimaerically&year_start=1988&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchimeric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimerical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimerically%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimaeric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimaerical%3B%2Cc0)). I'm in favor of splitting *chimerically* into two different lexemes. It's also possible, but seemingly rare, for a BrE writer to use *chimaerically*, which would add to the lemma *chimerically*.

examples:
"The **chimerically** clonal grape The problems posed by clonality, collectivity, and chimerism are brought together... in the case of Pinot meunier"
- *Darwinian Populations and Natural Selection* (2009)

"Suppose Hailey hallucinates a **chimerically** colored dragon."
- *The Sources of Intentionality* (2011)